# OCR in Word 2013

Tags: ocr, word-2013-preview

Word 2013 can naively open and edit PDF documents (big plus in my opinion). Is there a way to get it do some OCR as well?

On a PDF that that had mostly pictures, even the parts that were pure text were kept as images. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: The Office OCR tools will already do this, so I doubt it would be built into the PDF editor.

Comment: @RandolphWest, how do I use them (or even find them)?

Comment: I don't have them installed. I've in the past been able to import JPEG scans and use the OCR stuff for that (Office 2003).

Comment: Did you really just say that your word processor can open and edit documents?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Edited, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open scanned PDF with Word 2013 directly. An OCR tool is needed to help you turn scanned PDF into normal ones. Here you can get the answer:
http://blog.ipubsoft.com/open-scanned-pdf-with-ms-office-word-2013/

Comment: As of now , Google Docs has no longer that kind of type thing. I followed the instructions and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The way I normally do this is to paste the PDF into either Microsoft OneNote if you have it installed or into EverNote.

Both of these are able to OCR images into text quite well and they allow you to select the OCR'd text to copy and paste elsewhere - or you can leave it where it is since they both act as highly capable notebooks.

Not quite the answer you were looking for I know but I hope it may be of use anyway.